# Find filegroup of a heap table programmatically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table say, `My_Table`, which does not have any indexes. I need to find under which file group it belongs to programmatically.

All the solution I searched on the internet requires an index to be present in the table.
somewhat like below..

```
SELECT o.[name], o.[type], i.[name], i.[index_id], f.[name]
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups f
  ON i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o
  ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE i.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
  AND i.data_space_id = 2 -- Filegroup
GO
```

How to know the same if the table doesn't have any indexes?

**version** : `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR)`

Comment: You can know it by opening properties page of that table and check the `storage` tab

Comment: yes that is possible but I need it in query

Comment: A table still has an index on it if it hasn't had one created, it's just a heap index. The above will still return data if any of the tables have their data stored on Filegroup 2. Presumably the reason you get no result is because none of your heaped tables are on that file. If I use `i.data_space_id = 1` on my Sandbox, I get plenty of rows.

Comment: [From the documentation on `sys.indexes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `index_id`  `int`  ID of the index. `index_id` is unique only within the object. **0 = Heap**

Comment: Perhaps, therefore, what you should be doing is removing the clause `AND i.data_space_id = 2`? Seems like a non-reproducible/typgraphical error now to me.

Comment: @Larnu The filegroup id I had put is different from what I wanted. Now it works after changing.